# Is possible to make an internal connection with Appsync GrapQL?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, amazon-dynamodb

For some context i have the following code:

```
 type Product
  @model
  @key(name: "byProductCategory", fields: ["productCategoryID", "name"])
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: groups, groups: ["Driver", "Restaurant"], operations: [read] }
      {
        allow: groups
        groups: ["SuperAdmin"]
        operations: [read, create, update, delete]
      }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  productCategoryID: ID!
  name: String!
  brand: String!
  mainImage: Image @connection
  images: [Image] @connection(keyName: "byProduct", fields: ["id"])
  description: String
  category: ProductCategory @connection(fields: ["productCategoryID"])
  alternative: [Product]
  byproduct: [Byproduct]
}
```

I want to show a list of Alternative Products of product type but doesn't let me. I try to make a `@connection` but in some cases GrapQL compiler doesn't let me in others I can see it but can't insert a new alternative via Mutation.
Also tried to follow the next example. It was possible to Query but no mutate it
https://www.apollographql.com/blog/explaining-graphql-connections-c48b7c3d6976/